# Error:Execution failed for task

Tags: android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/NOTICE
>       File1: C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication3\httpclient-4.5.1\httpclient-4.5.1.jar
>       File2: C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication3\httpcore-4.0-beta1\httpcore-4.0-beta1.jar

i uploaded those library  at first they use to work perfectly when i uploaded android studio to  new version  it gives me this error

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your gradle file(app)

```
android {
 packagingOptions {
  exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
  exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
  exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
  exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
  exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
  exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
  exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
  exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
  exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
  exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
 }
}
```